# If $\mu_i \to \mu$ weakly, then do we have $\operatorname{supp}(\mu_i) \to \operatorname{supp}(\mu)$ in Hausdorff distance?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, weak-convergence

Suppose $\mu_i$ are Radon measures with support in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Is it true that if $\mu_i \to \mu$ weakly then their supports must converge in Hausdorff distance?

Comment: Consider $\delta_0 + 1/n \delta_1$.

Comment: Right, thanks. That's a no then.